# Why requests is no sending data?

Tags: python, post, python-requests, python-3.6

I made simply server.

This Server is return post raw data.
So, When I use Restlet Client in Chrome Extension to Server, I can return my json post data.

But, Python Requests module is no return.
I think `requests` did not send data.

Python 3.6.8
Requests 2.21.0
PHP 7

In PHP:

```php
<?php
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

In Python:

```
    try:
        task = self.q.get_nowait()
        # json_data = json.dumps(task)
        if 'picture' in task['data']:
            filename = task['data']['picture']
        else:
            filename = ''

        try:
            task['uuid'] = self.uuid
            if filename == '':
                url = 'http://server_domin/upload_nopic.php'
                data = json.dumps(task)
                print('task: ' + data)
                r = requests.post(url, data=data)
                print("Response: %s" % r.json())
            else:
                url = 'http://server_domin/upload.php'
                files = {'file': open('./images/' + filename, 'rb')}
                print('task: ' + json.dumps(task))
                r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=json.dumps(task))
                print("Response: %s" % r.json())

            # print("Response: %s" % str(r.text()))

        except Exception as ex:
            print("Upload Failure. ", filename, ex)
            traceback.print_stack()
            traceback.print_exc()

    except queues.QueueEmpty:
        pass
```

I checked the data(variable) just before sending and the response after sending.
data is saved normally, but response recieved empty data.

In Variable `data`:

```
{
  "data": {
    "utc": 1563862224,
    "accel": {
      "ax": -2.3630770385742186,
      "ay": 6.636727001953124,
      "az": 6.009446166992187
    },
    "gyro": {
      "gx": -4.137404580152672,
      "gy": -0.1297709923664122,
      "gz": 0.2366412213740458
    },
    "angle": {
      "ax": -14.785298705742603,
      "ay": 45.78478003457668,
      "az": 49.535035853061935
    },
    "temp": 26.459411764705884
  },
  "uuid": "ac2bbe96-5c2d-b960-6b88-40693bfb6a39"
}
```

In `requests.text()`:

```py
'' or Array()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote server probably wants a JSON as an input.

And since you use

```py
data = json.dumps(task)
requests.post(url, data=data)
```

and

```py
requests.post(url, files=files, data=json.dumps(task))
```

without setting `Content-Type: application/json` header, remote server may be unable to understand your HTTP request.

---

When you want to send a JSON, use `json=data`, not `data=data`. [It will set](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) appropriate `Content-Type` for you automatically.

Example:

```py
data = {
    "uuid": "ac2bbe96-5c2d-b960-6b88-40693bfb6a39",
    "utc": 1563862224
    # ... other data
}
r = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(r.status_code, r.text)  # it is always a good idea to check response HTTP status code
```